# Set Firebase local emulator cloud function environment config values

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When you update cloud function environment variables, the config values are not accessible when using the local node.js emulator.

On a project with no environment config variables:

- Set a new value `firebase functions:config:set x=true`
- Get the config variables `firebase functions:config:get` (shows the new value)
- Deploy the functions `firebase deploy --only functions`
- Run the local emulator and log out the `functions.config{}`
- Output: `{}` (empty object)

There is no mention in the [environment config docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) but I am assuming it is possible to use the same environment config locally (or a local alternative)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The answer was in the [local emulator documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional).

> Note: You can retrieve your production custom configuration variables
> when emulating functions. However, be cautious when using production
> config values in local testing of API calls, emails, etc.
>
> To use config variables, run the following command in the functions
> directory before running firebase serve.
>
> **MacOS**
>
> `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`
>
> **Windows**
>
> `firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json`

Comment: Warning: The above command won't work for Windows Powershell due to an issue with invisible characters preceding the JSON. Use `firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json` instead if using Powershell.

Comment: Also, the `.runtimeconfig.json` must be in the functions folder.

Comment: This documentation has been reworked since. Not sure if the proposed solution here actually solved the original problem, but unfortunately now it definitely doesn't do it anymore.

Comment: Do you just put the config keys/values into an object in the `.runtimeconfig.json`? There doesn't seem to be any documentation on what the file should actually contain.

Comment: Worked for me after putting it into functions folder. @twiz the file contents are whatever values you've previously set with functions:config:set to your cloud instance.  It's just json for a js object.  eg { "key": 123 }

Comment: @NikitaFuchs Thanks for pointing that out. I have improved the link to point specifically to the relevant section. As I asked the initial question, I found this information enough to solve the problem thus added this and accepted my answer. Hopefully, that clears up the confusion?

Comment: And take care to exclude `.runtimeconfig.json` from deployment  in `firebase.json >  functions > ignore` and in `.gitignore` if it has sensitive keys. 

`.runtimeconfig.json` is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional